# Arch on MacBook Air Touchpad Tap to Click/Drag will not turn off

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad, libinput

I am running Arch on a 2011 MacBook Air, and have been experiencing track pad issues off and on for quite some time. It seems that sometimes after system upgrades, the trackpad will become overly pressure sensitive and click when it is just slightly tapped or brushed. The touchpad is usable, but the extra clicks are very annoying. I have been trying to disable tap to click and tap and drag all together to prevent this issue from coming up in the first place, however I have not been able to get tap to click/drag to turn off.

In my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf file I have done:

```
# Match on all types of devices but joysticks
[...]
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Tapping" "false"
        Option "TapAndDragGesture" "false"
        Option "TappingDrag" "false"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
[...]
```

However the touchpad does not seem to have been affected at all by disabling the options. Am I doing something wrong?